# is there a search class for whether the drug was taken in hospital or not?

Tags: openfda, medical

is there a search class in open FDA Drug Adverse Event Report Browser for whether the drug was taken in hospital or not?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, OpenFDA Drug AE endpoint does not provide such information at this time.